# Unable to format/add a partition to Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, formatting

I recently add a 1T disk to an XP machine. I found the disk in the "disk management", I click "initialize" to init it, then creates a primary partition with size 950G, then select quick format to format the disk, the "disk management" will then complains:

> The disk configuration operation did
>   not complete. Check the system event
>   log for  more information on the
>   error. Verify the status of your
>   storage devices  before retrying. If
>   that does not solve the problem, close
>   the disk  management console, then
>   restart disk management or restart the
>   computer.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What was the additional information on the error in the event log?

Comment: Found the followings:

The device, \Device\Harddisk1\D, has a bad block.
The fault tolerant driver could not read the on disk structures from disk 1.
The device, \Device\Ide\IdePort1, did not respond within the timeout period.
The device 'WDC WD10EVDS-63U8B0' (IDE\DiskWDC_WD10EVDS-63U8B0_____________________01.00A01\5&8b4669c&0&0.0.0) disappeared from the system without first being prepared for removal.

Seems to be a disk failure?

Comment: Sounds like warranty time! or try a long format.

Answer (score 0):

confirmed to be hard disk problem...first time to met a brand new bad disk.

Comment: Really? I'm jealous. Normally, I get one bad drive per time I order drives.